# QWebElement or QWebFrame without QWebPage

Tags: c++, html, qt, parsing, qwebelement

I receive a HTML page in a thread (not the main thread). I would like to use the HTML parsing that's provided with QWebElement, but for that I need QWebPage. Since QWebPage is creating widgets and thus cannot be created in a different thread, how would I go about doing what I want?

Here's my try at this, but it is not working.

```
QString content = "<body><div id="hsearch"><form id="search" action="/search" method="get"><div><input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="search"></div></form></div><br class="cbt"><div id="hlogo"><a href="/">Stack Overflow</a></div></body>"; // Ignore the quotes and stuff, content is actually retrieved via QNetworkAccessManager

QWebElement docElement;
docElement.setPlainText(content);

QString stackLogoText = docElement.findFirst("a").toInnerXml; // Should return Stack Overflow
```

But it is not working - just returns an empty string. I also tried `setOuterXml()` and `setInnerXML()` ...

Any ideas?

Comment: check out signals and slots. You should be able to connect a slot across threads to provide the content from `QNetworkAccessManager` to your `QWebPage`

Comment: The QWebPage is accessed by more than one thread, so it wouldn't be such a good idea :(

Comment: Why not? You might need some critical sections or barriers during initializing of content but `connect` is thread safe by default.

Comment: I was not talking about connect(), but there are going to be around 5 of these threads running simultaneously and with each trying to set the HTML of the main frame in QWebPage ... I am new to threads, please enlighten me if I can make it work somehow the way you are mentioning?

Comment: Basically a critical section is a sequencing point where you can lock access. So the first thread makes the others wait to touch a particular non-thread safe bit of code. That way they don't overwrite each other or cause issues. For an example check out `QMutex` and `QMutexLocker`